# Turning 2d matrix into 3d matrix

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, 3d

I realize there are multiple threads concerning this topic, however non of the answers have worked for me yet. Right now, I have a 2D matrix with 6720 rows, and 3 variables. The first variable is date, which should consist of 112 slices (each day should represent a slice). Furthermore, each slice should have 60 rows. However, the values in the 3D matrix should be of the following two variables, and not date. The problem is that whenever I try to transform it, it only takes the date as the values.

```
final.dataset <- array(data = final.dataset, dim = c(60, 2, 112))
```

[This is what the current dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL7EO.png)
[instead, the variables mean_flourishing and picture_id should be the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsXkU.png)

Comment: That's not a matrix, it's a dataframe.  It has both date types and numeric types so it can't be a matrix or array:  they must be all one type.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2554330 stated, this is a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`. You can split the `data.frame` by the date and then convert it to an array:

```r
DF = data.frame(date = rep(seq.Date(as.Date('2013-03-23'), by = "1 day", length.out = 3), each = 4L),
                Mean_Flourishing = 1:12,
                picture_idx = 1:12 + 12L)

array(unlist(split(DF[-1L], DF[1L])), dim = c(4L, 2L, 3L))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   13
[2,]    2   14
[3,]    3   15
[4,]    4   16

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5   17
[2,]    6   18
[3,]    7   19
[4,]    8   20

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   21
[2,]   10   22
[3,]   11   23
[4,]   12   24

## original look of data.
DF
         date Mean_Flourishing picture_idx
1  2013-03-23                1          13
2  2013-03-23                2          14
3  2013-03-23                3          15
4  2013-03-23                4          16
5  2013-03-24                5          17
6  2013-03-24                6          18
7  2013-03-24                7          19
8  2013-03-24                8          20
9  2013-03-25                9          21
10 2013-03-25               10          22
11 2013-03-25               11          23
12 2013-03-25               12          24
```

Next time, please include data in your question and not pictures.